# How do I get my chest armor back?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

I just started the Heart of Stones quest line in New Game+, and after

> killing the frog king I was abducted onto a ship. The ship crashed

and when landing ashore I lost my chest armor.

It was a fully upgraded and master crafted Witcher's armor, so I am quite fond of it. Yet I cannot find it my inventory nor in the loot surrounding the ship.

Is it gone or can I get it back? If so, where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested another savegame, and then I kept the armor. It was in my inventory after the fight.

So it seems that is a bug. I am not sure what triggered it, yet the playthrough that was affected was a new game plus; the one working fine was a normal one.